# get different results of messages from AsyncFacebookRunner from different APPs

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

In the example "stream" of Facebook SDK, it use AsyncFacebookRunner to get messages, such as new AsyncFacebookRunner(fb).request("me/home", new StreamRequestListener());. It only gets post messages.

In my APP I do the same thing, but I got more messages, such as changing settings or oicons messages (The SDK example does not). Why?

Thank you.